# Show new methods in event toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, methods, custom-controls

is it possible to show new methods(of any custom control) in properties -> events tab in visual studio?
The same way as it showing properties of custom controls.
Thanks!

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: because some programmers are too lazy to go to the code and they want just to click a whole day :)

Comment: You could use Solution navigator (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx), it is a part of Productivity Power Tools.